# Дублирование набора текстбоксов по нажатию кнопки - C#/.NET 4.x

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

Я работаю небольшим руководителем и дополнительно увлекаюсь программированием на С#. Каждый раз когда с бухгалтерии присылают сумму денег, я не могу выдать ее работникам не разменяв. Обычно с бухгалтерии присылают сумму в которой самой мелкой купюрой является 100 рублей, но зарплаты у сотрудников обычно не кратны 100 рублям, а имеют вид, например: 87 645 рубля и т.д.
У меня возникла идея написать программу, которая бы остаток от деления зарплаты сотрудника на 100 раскладывала по номиналам монет, и у меня получилось. Вот screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUf7X.jpg т.е. 45 рублей разложились на четыре 10-ки и одну 5-ку.

Вот код этой программы:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const int nominal_quant = 5;
    int delitel = 100;
    int zarplata = Convert.ToInt32(this.textBox1.Text);
    int ostatok = zarplata % delitel;
    TextBox[] text_box = new TextBox[nominal_quant] {
        this.textBox2, this.textBox3, this.textBox4, this.textBox5, this.textBox6
    };
    int[] nominals = new int[nominal_quant] {
        50, 10, 5, 2, 1
    };
    int[] coin_quant = new int[nominal_quant];

    for (int i = 0; i < nominals.Length; i++) {
        while (ostatok >= nominals[i]) {
            ostatok -= nominals[i];
            coin_quant[i]++;
        }
        text_box[i].Text = coin_quant[i].ToString();
    }
}

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    char ch = e.KeyChar;
    //Если символ, введенный с клавы - не цифра (IsDigit),
    if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8)
    {
        // то событие не обрабатывается. ch!=8 (8 - это Backspace)
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Как можно без рутины размножить этот код для 12-ти сотрудников? Сейчас код написан только для одной зарплаты (одного сотрудника)
Так же, я хотел бы прочитать комментарии по способам суммирования 50-к по всем сотрудникам, 10-к по всем сотрудникам и т.д. Для получения общего количества тех или иных монет, чтобы понимать с какой суммой денег идти разменивать и как именно разменять эту сумму.

Comment: Контролы тоже можно помещать в массивы и обращаться к ним по индексу. Ну и один и тот же обработчик можно подписать на события нескольких контролов.

Comment: Андрей, можете свой ответ в коде показать?

Comment: попрактиковался [на bash-е](https://github.com/sash-kan/coins)

Comment: Александр, благодарю! Хочу дождаться вариантов на c#.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov, не пишу под WinForms, если вас устроит WPF-решение, то могу показать как бы я написал. Но принцип создания контролов сильно будет отличаться, ибо в WPF они будут создаваться автоматически по шаблону. Может быть в WinForms это тоже возможно, но я не знаю.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ясно. WPF пока еще предстоит изучить...

Comment: Ну если вы только начинаете изучать десктопные фреймворки, можете изучать сразу WPF, а WinForms проигнорировать, ибо преимуществ он никаких перед WPF не имеет. А вот WPF более гибок, но, местами, более сложен, конечно. А принцип построения интерфейса сильно отличается, WPF больше похож на разметку веб-страниц и т.п.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ок, спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 2):

Не прошло и 7 часов ;)) Решил с помощью listBox!

```
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8) //Если символ, введенный с клавы - не цифра (IsDigit),
        {
            e.Handled = true;// то событие не обрабатывается. ch!=8 (8 - это Backspace)
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.listBox1.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const int nominal_quant = 5;
        TextBox[] text_box = new TextBox[nominal_quant] { this.textBox2, this.textBox3, this.textBox4, this.textBox5, this.textBox6 };
        int[] nominals = new int[nominal_quant] { 50, 10, 5, 2, 1 };
        int[] coin_quant = new int[nominal_quant];
        string [] workers_zarplata = new string [listBox1.Items.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            workers_zarplata[i] = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
            int zarplata = Convert.ToInt32(workers_zarplata[i]);
            int delitel = 100;
            int ostatok = zarplata % delitel;

            for (int j = 0; j < nominals.Length; j++)
            {
                while (ostatok >= nominals[j])
                {
                    ostatok -= nominals[j];
                    coin_quant[j]++;
                }
                text_box[j].Text = coin_quant[j].ToString();
            }
            int quant_50 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            int quant_10 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
            int quant_5 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
            int quant_2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
            int quant_1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text);
            int coin_summa = (quant_50 * 50) + (quant_10 * 10) + (quant_5 * 5) + (quant_2 * 2) + quant_1;

            textBox7.Text = coin_summa.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Screenshot интерфейса https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HxZJ.jpg

Всем спасибо!